# Creating JSON from stacks

Tags: c#

I have stacks of strings that contain values like:

`catalog`

`catalog`, `type`

`catalog`, `type`, `offer`

`catalog`, `type`, `active`

I want to get a JSON structure like:

```
{ catalog: 
  { type: 
    {
      offer: '',
      active: ''
    }
  },
}
```

I attempted this:

```
private static string BuildJsonStringFromStack(Stack<string> stack)
    {
        if (stack.Count == 1)
        {
            return $"{{{stack.Pop()}: {{}}}}";
        }

        var json = new StringBuilder("{");
        var depth = stack.Count;
        while (stack.Any())
        {
            if (stack.Count == 1)
            {
                json.Append($"{stack.Pop()}: ''");
                json.Append(new String('}', depth));
            }
            else
            {
                json.Append($"{stack.Pop()}: {{");
            }
        }
        return json.ToString();
    }
```

This would give me strings like:

```
{ catalog: 
  { type: 
    {
      offer: ''
     }
   }
}

{ catalog: 
  { type: 
    {
      active: ''
     }
   }
}
```

However, when I attempted to merge the strings into a `JObject`, I would not get both `offer` and `active` as children of `type` - the last one processed would overwrite the other.

```
var jObject = JObject.Parse(BuildJsonStringFromStack(stack));
requestJson.Merge(jObject, new JsonMergeSettings
{
    MergeArrayHandling = MergeArrayHandling.Merge
});
```

Any thoughts as to how I can get the merge I want?

Comment: You could create an object in C# that reflects the data hierarchy (like a POCO,) populate it similarly to the logic you have in your question, then convert it to json.

Comment: You can use ExpandoObjects to recreate the structure (casted as dynamic) and then serialize it

Comment: @Gusman Good call, I've added an answer with my working first pass.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Gusman's comment, it was pretty simple:

```
 dynamic expando = new ExpandoObject();

 foreach (var stack in stacks)
 {
     CreateExpando(expando, stack);
 }
 return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(expando);
```

Which calls:

```
 private static void CreateExpando(ExpandoObject expando, Stack<string> stack)
    {
        var expandoDict = expando as IDictionary<string, object>;
        var item = stack.Pop();

        ExpandoObject expandoRef = new ExpandoObject();
        if (!expandoDict.Keys.Contains(item)) {
            expandoDict.Add(item, expandoRef);
        }
        else {
            expandoRef = expandoDict[item] as ExpandoObject;
        }
        if (stack.Any())
        {
            CreateExpando(expandoRef, stack);
        }            
    }
```